# Store in variable instead of write to console?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

See [GitHub](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp/blob/master/JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Feedback.Test/Program.cs)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // do something...

    service.Feedback += new FeedbackService.OnFeedback(service_Feedback);
}

static void service_Feedback(object sender, Feedback feedback)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Feedback - Timestamp: {0} - DeviceId: {1}", feedback.Timestamp, feedback.DeviceToken));
}
```

Instead of output for display in the console how do you store it into a variable so it can be in the main program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'd need to declare the variable:

```
static Feedback lastFeedback;
```

and then simply assign it in the method:

```
static void service_Feedback(object sender, Feedback feedback)
{
    lastFeedback = feedback;
}
```

You might want to consider making this a `List<Feedback>` instead of only storing the last feedback received.

Note that if there are multiple threads involved, you'll need to take extra care - particularly if you're using a collection. (`List<T>` isn't thread-safe.)

Of course you don't *have* to use a method for the event handler:

```
service.Feedback += (sender, feedback) => lastFeedback = feedback;
```

It depends on how comfortable you are with lambda expressions. Even if you don't want to do it inline like that, you could still make your existing handler subscription slightly simpler using a method group conversion:

```
service.Feedback += service_Feedback;
```

Comment: @001: I don't know what the GitHub API does with feedback. If it calls the event handler multiple times, you could just store the feedback in a collection as I suggested. I suggest you investigate that yourself, and ask any questions resulting from it.

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda:

```
class Program
{
    static string feedback; // string to store formatted string, use type Feedback to store the variable itself

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        service.Feedback += (s,f) => feedback = String.Format("Feedback - Timestamp: {0} - DeviceId: {1}", f.Timestamp, f.DeviceToken);
    }
}
```

or classic:

```
static void service_Feedback(object sender, Feedback f)
{
   feedback = string.Format("Feedback - Timestamp: {0} - DeviceId: {1}", f.Timestamp, f.DeviceToken);
}
```

This will store just the last feedback.

Comment: s? f? what I want to do is assign timestamp to a variable, assign devicetoken to another variable, then go to the next feedback.

Comment: @001: You didn't say you wanted two different variables, one for the timestamp and one for the device token. It's also not clear what you mean by "go to the next feedback".

Comment: Is it possible to get the first and second feedback?

Comment: @001: There is nothing about that in your original question. Please update it to clarify

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // do something...

    service.Feedback += new FeedbackService.OnFeedback(service_Feedback);
}

static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
static void service_Feedback(object sender, Feedback feedback)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Feedback - Timestamp: {0} - DeviceId: {1}", feedback.Timestamp, feedback.DeviceToken));
}
```